# GAS - onChange trigger (get value) from Active Sheet and Write to Another Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's what I'm trying to do,

Every time the user inserts a new row and adds a new value into spreadsheet 'A', the `onChange()` trigger will get the new value and insert the new value into spreadsheet 'B'.

I'm not sure how I can get the new value since it requires `onEdit()` as well.

```
function onChange(e){

  var editedRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedCol = editedRange.getColumn(); // integer

  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') {
    Logger.log("inserted");
    // get new value

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible. But perhaps a better mind than my can comment on this.

Unless I'm reading the question wrong, you're actually looking for two changes. First a new row is inserted, then a value is entered.

These are both seperate events. So I'm not sure code wise you can say IF this event happens and then this event. Do x.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question fully, if you have a demo sheet, or an example of what you want done, that would help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that what you want to do isn't possible at this time.  I've tried using different variations of simple and installed `onEdit` triggers with the installed `onChange` trigger, and can't get them to run at the same time.

The installable `onChange` trigger ***WILL*** check for an EDIT.  And that would work just fine except for one small problem.  You can't access the current cell, or determine what the current cell or range is with the installable `onChange` trigger.  For the current range, it always returns row one, no matter what row was edited.  I'd call it a bug.

I just found that it is reported in the issue tracker:

[Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3269&q=onChange&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)